# Laravel merging Eloquent result and array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to merge eloquent result and array because I need to add all possible filters that user can use for this model. If anyone have any other idea how to make it I really would be very thankful. Here is an example code:

```
<?php

class School extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'schools';

    public function listSchoolsEndUser()
    {
        $schools_data = new School;

        $schools_data = $schools_data->paginate(12);

        $filters = array( 
            'filters' => array(
                'name' => 'Neshtoto'
            )
        );

        $schools_data = (object) array_merge(get_object_vars($schools_data), $filters);

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $schools_data );
        exit;

        return $schools_data;
    }
```

And the result is very interesting:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [filters] => Array
        (
            [name] => Neshtoto
        )

)
```

Comment: Please provide an example including the expected result

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send both, `filters` and the `school_data` back in a JSON response you can do it this way:

```
return Response::json(array(
   'filters' => array(
        'name' => 'Neshtoto'
    ),
    'data' => $school_data->toArray()
));
```

Or if you want to use `array_merge`:

```
$school_data = array_merge($filters, array('data' => $school_data->toArray()));
return $school_data;
```

### Edit

If you are just injecting the data into a view I see no reason at all to merge the data, just pass two variables!

```
return View::make('view', array('schools' => $school_data, 'filters' => $filters));
```

(Here `$filters` would obviously only be `array('name' => 'Neshtoto')` and not the full thing including `'filters' => ...`)

Comment: Yes it's return array but then I can't use pagination and laravel throw `Trying to get property of non-object` in blade file. I'm using the simple foreach `@foreach($schools->data as $school)
....
@endForeach`. Is there any reason to keep laravel's pagination and add filters?

Comment: Ah you're passing it to a view? Didn't look like that in your question. Editing now...

Comment: Yes, I can be more descriptive. Sorry

Comment: Thank you dude :) I'm just beginner in laravel and sorry if I'm asking a bit silly questions.